# Firebase onCall method finishes before code execution completes

Tags: node.js, firebase

I have a rather intensive Node function that includes multiple aync tasks that waits for the previous action to complete prior to going to the next step. It's crucial that the entire task finishes when it is called. I'm seeing issues where the `onCall` function will end before the code execution finishes. I can see this in the logs, as I'm console logging the various methods called from top to bottom until the function is "complete". The parent function is here:

```
exports.myHandyFunction = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const response = async () => {
      try {
        let result = await some_main_function_elsewhere_in_code();
        resolve(result)
      } catch (err) {
        console.log('parent promise caught error:')
        console.log(err)
        reject(err)
      }
    }

    response()
  })
})
```

I've increased the function's timeout from 60s to 240s hoping that this is purely a function timeout issue? This is pretty troubling, as I have some complex logic being called that ends up not fully completing. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `response` function is async. When you call it, you're not awaiting for it's execution. This is leading on the premature end of the oncall method execution.

Instead of wrapping the business logic inside an async function, wrapped inside a promise, you can change the code like this:

```
exports.myHandyFunction = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
  return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
    try {
      let result = await some_main_function_elsewhere_in_code();
      resolve(result)
    } catch (err) {
      console.log('parent promise caught error:')
      console.log(err)
      reject(err)
    }
  })
})
```

Basically, the Promise is declared as async, so we can use the await constructor inside of it. Then, we just have to call the some_main_function_elsewhere_in_code method, awaiting for it.